# ASP.Net Core MVC на Ubuntu Server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Здравствуйте. 
Имеется удалённый сервер на Ubuntu Server 16.04. 
На нём планируется запустить Web-сайт.

Можно ли как-то настроить так, чтобы работать в IDE на своей машине, а при запуске оно отправлялось на сервер и запускалось там? В браузере бы открывался уже сайт на удалённом сервере вместо localhost.

Просто мой ноутбук довольно слабый и сборка и запуск занимают много времени, а вот скорость интернета и у меня и на сервере отличная. Плюс не пришлось бы тратить время на развёртывание уже готового приложения из Windows в Linux.

Comment: Используйте какой-нибудь https://appharbor.com/

Comment: [Debugging .NET Core on Unix over SSH](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/01/26/debugging-net-core-on-unix-over-ssh/)

Comment: @Bulson там не показано как правильно развернуть проект на самом сервере.. лишь подключиться к уже готовому и демонизированному..

Comment: я пробовал два разных мануала, один с сайта майкрософта, другой с хабра и оба с ошибками на этапе запуска демона в systemd =/ https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore1x  |  https://habrahabr.ru/post/332920/

Comment: @Bulson забил на демонизацию.. собрал и запустил вручную проект на сервере, присоединился по ssh в Visual Studio, но всё что я вижу это консольный лог. как мне получить возможность редактировать исходники на сервере и собирать их там же (на сервере) и запускать?

Comment: @Bulson вот всё что я вижу после присоединения к процессу по ssh - http://pastexen.com/i/MhQC4vS46u.png

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вам надо открывать в студии проект, который уже лежит на сервере. По-моему здесь надо использовать GIT. На сервере создать из проекта репозиторий, далее с него с помощью гита получить копию проекта на ноутбук, далее по необходимости пушить на сервер изменения обратно. Но это в теории, я такого опыта не имею, извините, больше ничего подсказать по этой проблеме не смогу.

Answer (score 1):

Правой кнопкой мыши по проекту в иерархии, там есть кнопка "Опубликовать".
Далее настраивается доступ по ftp к серверу и прописывается каталог.
При нажатии "Опубликовать", ноутбук будет компилировать проект и сразу же заливать все файлы на сервер.
После чего можно зайти по ip или доменному имени и увидеть все внесенные изменения.

Comment: послу публикации через ftp на сервер залилась папка Release со скомпилированными бинарниками вместо самого проекта =/

Comment: плюс, после каждого изменения он снова заливает все файлы на фтп, независимо от того изменялись они или нет, а это довольно долго. не из-за скорости интернета, но из-за их количества, я полагаю =\